# Determine elements of a matrix when sum of rows and columns are given

Tags: matrix, sum, computation

There is 4x4 matrix with all 4 diagonal elements zero. All other elements are non negative integers. Sum of all 4 rows and 4 columns are known individually. Is it possible to determine the remaining 12 elements of the matrix? Eg

```
0      1     1     0   sum=2
2      0     0     1   sum=3
4      1     0     0   sum=5
0      1     6     0   sum=7
sum=6 sum=3 sum=7 sum=1
```

Any guidance will be very helpful.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The matrix is

0 a<sub>12</sub> a<sub>13</sub> a<sub>14</sub>

a<sub>21</sub> 0 a<sub>23</sub> a<sub>24</sub>

a<sub>31</sub> a<sub>32</sub> 0 a<sub>34</sub>

a<sub>41</sub> a<sub>42</sub> a<sub>43</sub> 0

The problem is to solve a set of linear equations:

a<sub>12</sub> + a<sub>13</sub> + a<sub>14</sub> = c<sub>1</sub>

a<sub>21</sub> + a<sub>23</sub> + a<sub>24</sub> = c<sub>2</sub>

and so on. We have 12 variables and 8 equations (4 for the rows and 4 for the columns). To solve a linear equation system in 12 variables, we generally need 12 equations. Since the number of equations is lesser, the system will not have a unique solution. It may have infinitely many solutions.

Comment: He is asking for answers with non negative integers. Since the row sums are upper bounds for the possible solution coefficients, the possible solution space is finite. Thus your comment about infintely many solutions is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

The matrix is

0 a<sub>12</sub> a<sub>13</sub> a<sub>14</sub>

a<sub>21</sub> 0 a<sub>23</sub> a<sub>24</sub>

a<sub>31</sub> a<sub>32</sub> 0 a<sub>34</sub>

a<sub>41</sub> a<sub>42</sub> a<sub>43</sub> 0

The problem is to solve a set of linear equations:

a<sub>12</sub> + a<sub>13</sub> + a<sub>14</sub> = r<sub>1</sub>

a<sub>21</sub> + a<sub>23</sub> + a<sub>24</sub> = r<sub>2</sub>

a<sub>31</sub> + a<sub>32</sub> + a<sub>34</sub> = r<sub>3</sub>

a<sub>41</sub> + a<sub>43</sub> + a<sub>44</sub> = r<sub>4</sub>

a<sub>21</sub> + a<sub>31</sub> + a<sub>41</sub> = c<sub>1</sub>

a<sub>12</sub> + a<sub>32</sub> + a<sub>42</sub> = c<sub>2</sub>

a<sub>13</sub> + a<sub>23</sub> + a<sub>43</sub> = c<sub>3</sub>

a<sub>14</sub> + a<sub>34</sub> + a<sub>44</sub> = c<sub>4</sub>

Thus you need to solve an equation of the form Ax = b with A consisting of only 0 and 1 coefficients. Use Gauss Elimination and Euclidian Algorithm to find **integer** Matrices S, D, T such that D is in Diagonal form and SDT = A. If you do not know how to do this search the web for [Smith normal form algorithm.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smith_normal_form)

Then

SDTx = Ax = b

Thus

DTx = S<sup>-1</sup>Ax = S<sup>-1</sup>b

Since D is in diagonal form you can check if you can solve

Dy = S<sup>-1</sup>b

for y. You also find a base for the (Homogenous) solution space. This in turn can then be used to cut down the complexity in the search for the positive solutions of the original equation.